# IOS CABasicAnimation rotation and touch frame

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a subclass of a UIView which is being rotated using a CABasicAnimation. I also want this rotated view to be touched by users to trigger some event. However I am finding that applying a rotation to my view seems to mess up the touchable area of my view. The view appears correctly after being rotated but it appears that only half of the view is touchable. The touchesBegan method does not fire on portions of the view even though the touch is clearly on the view. Is there something that I need to do to correct the frame of a view after it has been rotated so that it can be interacted with properly?

This is my rotation code:

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angle];
fullRotation.duration = 0.0;
fullRotation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
fullRotation.autoreverses = NO;
fullRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
fullRotation.repeatCount = 0;
[self.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

From doing a few NSLogs I can indeed see that the frame of the view is not being modified after the animation is added despite the fact that the view looks different visually.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using CGAffineTransform to do my rotation. Just be sure to not modify the frame once a rotation has been applied, if the view needs to be moved you should use view.center instead of view.frame.

```
CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
self.transform = transformRotate;
```